# nested this pointer in javascript

Tags: javascript, draw2d

I'm using draw2d js library. I have the following code that creates a rectangle on the canvas.

```
 var rect = new draw2d.shape.basic.Rectangle({x:20,y:30});
 rect.on("click", function(){
     //var that = this;
    alert("test");
// I'm trying to access rect using this keyword but its not working
    var c = new draw2d.Connection();
    this.createPort('hybrid'); // adds a port on the rectangle



});
```

I'm trying to access rect using this keyword but its not working

Thanks!

Comment: "its not working" probably wont get you very far here. What exactly is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` in that context does not refer to `rect`, but instead refers to the anonymous function you provided to `on`:

```
function(){
  alert("test");
  var c = new draw2d.Connection();
  this.createPort('hybrid'); // adds a port on the rectangle
} // => This is what `this` refers to.
```

You can just reference `rect` directly:

```
var rect = new draw2d.shape.basic.Rectangle({x:20,y:30});
rect.on("click", function(){
  alert("test");
  var c = new draw2d.Connection();
  rect.createPort('hybrid'); // adds a port on the rectangle
});
```

`this` is a fairly tricky point of JavaScript. I'd recommend reading [Mozilla's guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to grok it better.